# Impelement Android InAppBilling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-billing

recently i develop an application with flutter Now I am at a level that I want to add In_App_Billing for markets like Google Play store and ...
Does anyone have an experience doing this that can help me?

I tried to add googleplay inAppBilling libraries but android studio Could not resolved them

Comment: Please post your stack trace. And did you try this [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase)?

Comment: yes, thanks
but I want to use this in another market. It has a Google play store InAppBilling-like structure

Comment: Can't help you much then :(

Comment: it was perfent. tnx bro